(Cs)What value do I have to give args in this function?
So some friends and me  are programming a consolegame in Cs and I want to do a function (progressClick) which requires a int (in this case a coordinate for a rectangle) But it says that I dont have a correct value for the int even tho i gave them one (100).
The problem which gets shown is following: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter "Ycord" of MyMinigame6.progressClick(EventArgs, int)" (CS7036)
If i hower my mouse over OnClick it says: "Action? SVGElement.OnClick {get; set;}" So i believe OnClick is an EventHandler
What do I have to do?
        AddElement(
                  new Circle()
                  {
                      //Hand zum klicken
                      R = 100,
                      CX = 550,
                      CY = 500,
                      Fill = "orange",
                      Stroke = "red",
                      StrokeWidth = 40,
                      OnClick = progressClick(100),
                  }

              );

        Update();
    }


    public void progressClick(EventArgs args, int Ycord)
    {


        AddElement(
                   new Rectangle()
                   {
                       X = 150,
                       Y = Ycord,
                       Width = 10,
                       Height = 60,
                       Fill = "transparent",
                       Stroke = "orange",
                       StrokeWidth = 100
                   }
               );

        Update();
    }


I tried doing a function without Eventargs args but then there was a mistake with the void in "public void" part of the function

It does not only have an int but also an EventArgs parameter that you ignore. Is OnClick an EventHandler? Maybe you should show also how OnClick is defined in Circle. That should give us ideas how to properly help.

In addition to what @Ralf said, if you have syntax or compiler errors, copy-paste them, don't paraphrase.

@Ralf The problem which gets shown is following:
"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter "Ycord" of MyMinigame6.progressClick(EventArgs, int)" (CS7036)
I am not 100% sure if OnClick is an Eventhandler but I believe so. If i hower my mouse on OnClick it says "Action? SVGElement.OnClick {get; set;}
OnClick is from the Framework we use which got made by someone we know but currently I can't contact him.

Then remove the integer from the progressClick method. The method will be called from the Circle class with the parameters the class wants to give to your method. its not in your hands. Then simply apply the method to onclick like OnClick = progressClick. If it compiles you got the correct signature of the method. Then you can think off different ways to get Ycord into the method. Currently i can just say its useless as it is a constant. And so you can just directly use 100 instead of a parameter.
